# Difference between Android application project and Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, java-7

I am a beginner starting to learn android application development. Most of the Tutorials I have come through show screenshots of getting an option saying 'Android Project' however the option I get says 'Android application project'. I just wanted to know if there is a difference between these two. I am running Windows 7 Pro 64 bit and Eclipse Juno and Java 7 and Android 4.1 SDK. The tutorials I see usually have older versions of all the software. So, it has been a bit confusing for me to follow them. I guess these are a beginner's teething problems. Can somebody help me get around them by suggesting me reference material that would help a beginner like me? Just so I dont hit anymore bumps like these. The palette view and everything else does not seem to be the same either. Which is the reason maybe why I got confused. Thank you for your time. All your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between android simple project and application project in new version Sdk Android application project is there 
difference means in Simple project default values are taken like Android Version and Sdk
But in Application Project there is chance to take manually these things

Answer (score 7):

> I just wanted to know if there is a difference between these two.

"Android Application Project" is the new name for "Android Project", more or less. Some things were moved into other wizards (e.g., "Android Project From Existing Source").